# Process start перекрывает главное окно

Tags: c#, процесс, dialogfragment

Запускаю стороннее приложение, однако он перекрывает основное окно и становится как будто модальным. Есть ли вариант сделать чтобы окно не перекрывало основную форму?

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("-m:{0} -a:0 -u:{1} -p:{2} -d:dg",pcname,login,password);
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();// Waits here for the process to exit.
```

Comment: Для начала, ваша проблема - вот в этой строчке: `process.WaitForExit();`

Comment: Именно эта строчка блокирует окно вашего приложения и делает окно дочернего процесса "как будто модальным"

Comment: если я это не сделаю окно не открывается

Comment: значит, у вас ошибка в другом месте

Comment: Эта строчка не влияет на открытие окна другой программы. Вы вообще не можете влиять на отображение окна другой программы кроме как загородив его или отобрав процессорное время. Дайте угадаю, у вас там ниже бесконечный цикл?

Comment: Что за операция, что требует ожидания выхода другого приложения? И в чем профит, если можно всен сделать в текущем потоке. Надо пустить все в асинхрон и использовать некоторые примитивы синхронизации. Какова цель? Примитивы подскажем.